# Listen to statusbar/navbar visibility in fullscreen mode?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity, android-view

In my activity I go fullscreen to hide the status bar and navigation bar using this code:

```kotlin
window.apply {
    decorView.systemUiVisibility = (
            View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_STABLE
                    or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_LAYOUT_FULLSCREEN
                    or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_HIDE_NAVIGATION
                    or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                    or View.SYSTEM_UI_FLAG_IMMERSIVE
            )
    addFlags(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN
                or WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS
    )
}
```

Android make it so the status bar and navigation bar can still temporary appear with a slide from the bottom or the top of the screen, how can I detect when this event happen? (it seems possible since the default Actionbar automatically show/hide with the status bar)

Comment: Hello Bencri, did you find a solution?

Comment: @K.tas Nope ...

Comment: I found and answered below. It helped me and hope it will help you too.